# How can I add at every time step inside a loop?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create an array of filenames in a loop where 5 minutes is added to every time step:

```
PE.20110612.000500.tif
PE.20110612.001000.tif
PE.20110612.001500.tif
```

Using this code

```
startYear = '2011';
startMon = '06';
startDate = '12';
startHour = '00';
startMin = '05';
endYear = '2011';
endMon = '06';
endDate = '12';
endHour = '00';
endMin = '30';

peFileNames=cell(1,20);
for k = 1:20
   peFileNames{k} = strcat('PE','.',startYear,startMon,startDate,'.',startHour,startMin,'00','.tif');
   startMin = startMin+5;
end
```

Obviously, this is not working as I am not able to add 5 minutes inside the loop at every time step. How can I do it?

The final idea is to go from StartTime to EndTime and create n number of cells inside an array.

Comment: Any particular reason you're doing it this way instead of using an actual date? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addtodate.html looks like it simplify what you're trying to do, you'd just have to format the date string for your file name.

Comment: Thanks. The date format (PE.20110612.000500.tif) comes from the data and it has to be kept that way. I am not sure how to convert this to a format that datenum can understand.... Addtodate would be very useful if I could...

Comment: I am checking the datenum documentation for more details....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of manually implementing the time addition, you can use the built-in `addtodate` function (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addtodate.html), which will automatically handle issues with rolling over to the next field:

```
startDate = datenum('12-Jun-2011 00:05:00');
endDate = datenum('12-Jun-2011 00:30:00')

peFileNames=cell(1,20);
for k = 1:20
   peFileNames{k} = strcat('PE.',datestr(startDate, 'yyyymmdd.HHMMSS'), '.tif');
   startDate = addtodate(startDate, 5, 'minute');
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting several errors including this one: Error using cnv2icudf (line 92)
Unrecognized month format.  Format string: yyyymmdd.hhmmss.

Comment: Oops, the second set of 'm's was supposed to be capitalized. Updated!

Comment: @maximusdooku Try the output format `'yyyymmdd.HHMMSS`.

Answer (score 2):

Without using the [`datetime`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) type (R2014b+), I'd create a vector of doubles and then convert them to strings:

```
startYear = '2011'  ;
startMon  = '06'    ;
startDate = '12'    ;
%
startmin = 5                                ;
freq     = 5                                ;
steps    = 20                               ;
minsraw  = (startmin:freq:(freq*steps)).'   ;%'
min      = mod(minsraw,60)                  ;
hour     = floor(minsraw/60)                ;
%
startMin  = num2str(min,'%02G') ;
startHour = num2str(hour,'%02G');

%   The curly braces around .tif makes the output a cell array.
peFileNames = strcat('PE','.',startYear,startMon,startDate,'.',startHour,startMin,'00',{'.tif'});
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of the datetime function.

Comment: @maximusdooku Indeed.  I added mine because this is how I would do it and for users that have older versions of Matlab without the type.